# Wrong value in Reputation

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

Even though it was a happy information for me , it was a mistake.

One of my SO tab was open for a long time, suddenly it shows  1510 reputation for me.

[image]

The most important thing is i had ever entered in 1500 reputation.Is there any bug , issues ?

Comment: The exact number of 15 suggests that someone accepted one of your answers, then unaccepted it again.

Comment: Then it should shows in my reputation list,right?

Comment: Not if you didn't open it before it was undone, at least when the action is undone sufficiently quickly.

Comment: Ok.Thats it. Thanks you @Servy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of your recent answers was accepted, then un-accepted again: [sharing a text file between android activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672087/sharing-a-text-file-between-andriod-activities/29672143#29672143)

Looking at the [timeline of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29672087/timeline) the OP tried to mark  both answers as accepted, then settled on the other post.

This means you *briefly* gained 15 points, then lost it again. The reputation notification system tries to focus on *achievements*, so the +15 was shown, but the subsequent -15 wasn't. Reload the page and your reputation will reflect the current value again.

I've left a comment on the question telling the OP that they can only mark one answer as accepted, not both. Perhaps they really meant yours to be the more helpful one, perhaps they wanted to it to be the other.